# What exactly handles the Ctrl+X shortcut family (e.g. Ctrl+X Ctrl+E) in Linux terminals?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I've seen a lot of online resources [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14255401/2153350) several compound shortcuts beginning with `Ctrl`+`X` :

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> : Edits the current line in the $EDITOR program, or vi
> if undefined.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> : Read in the contents of the inputrc file, and
> incorporate any bindings or variable assignments found there.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> : Incremental undo, separately remembered for each line.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> : Display version information about the current instance
> of bash.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> : Alternates the cursor with its old position. (C-x,
> because x has a crossing shape).

But I cannot find a single official documentation source that would list all of the possible `Ctrl`+`X`+`<something>` combinations, and I don't even know what would be the tool to look up the man of: is is bash? readline? xterm?

So what exactly handles these compound `Ctrl`+`X`+`<something>` shortcuts in Linux terminals?

Answer (score 4):

The characters handled directly by the linux terminal can be listed with `stty -a`.  Anything else is handled by the application you are running, and a list of the key sequences should be in the documentation for that application.

The application most likely involved here is your shell.  Most modern shells (including bash, zsh, others) either use the readline library or implement line editing themselves.  The readline library and most of the shells that do this without readline derive their key sequences from the `emacs` editor (although vi bindings may also be available), and in particularly ones that start with <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> are from emacs, and the <kbd>C-x</kbd> notation in particular (for ctrl-x) is from the emacs documenatation.  (Just for clarification -- emacs doesn't do this unless you are running emacs.  The applications just duplicated the functionality for their own use.)

Answer (score 3):

The thing that handles the `Ctrl`+`X`+`<something>` and much more is the 'readline' library and the documentation that covers it can be found in the [GNU bash man](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing).

The `Ctrl`+`<something>` shortcuts are somewhat cryptically described as `C-<something>` due to the fact that Control key may be named differently depending on your machine.

See also `/etc/inputrc` and possibly `/etc/inputrc.keys`.